# Single Email limit per execution using Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

How many emails can be sent using trigger per execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send as many as you need to, as long as you don't violate any of the governor limits. There is no specific limit to the number of emails that can be sent per execution. You are limited by a daily limit for non-user recipients, a per-transaction limit of 10 Messaging.sendEmail calls, and a maximum of 100 emails per Messaging.SingleMessage. It is conceptually possible to send 10,000+ emails in a single trigger execution if you design the code properly.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. @sfdcfox. Well explained! :)

Comment: Worth noting - usually 5000 emails is the standard limit per day. See this [related post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25184/single-email-limit-exceeded-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: @BrianMiller True, but only for leads and contacts. You can send as many emails to users as you'd like. I've tested up to 10,000 emails this way.