# First exception on row 3; first error: SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, Email limit exceeded

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, email-template

Am getting following error message `06:15:51:437 FATAL_ERROR System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 3; first error: SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, Email limit exceeded: []`.

There’s no limit on sending individual emails to contacts, leads, person accounts, Am using contact object to send an email even though it fails. Can some one help on this.

```
for(Invoice__c inv :(List<Invoice__c>) scope){


            Id TemplateId = NULL; 
            TemplateId = [SELECT Id,Name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName =: varEmailTemplateDeveloperName].Id;

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emails = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            emails.setTemplateId(TemplateId); 

            List<String> functionTypes = new List<String>();
            List <contact> conLst = new List<contact>([SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact where AccountId =:inv.Student_Family_Account__c AND Email != null ]);
            for(contact conObj : conLst){
                functionTypes.add(conObj.email);
                emails.setTargetObjectId(conObj.Id);
            }

            string emailStr = String.join(functionTypes, ';');
            List<string> varTOSendEmails =   emailStr.split(';');

            emails.setWhatId(inv.Id); 
            emails.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            emails.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
            emails.setToAddresses(varTOSendEmails);
            emailList.add(emails); 
    }    
    System.debug('You have made ' + Limits.getEmailInvocations() + ' email calls out of ' + Limits.getLimitEmailInvocations() + ' allowed');
    Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);
     System.debug('111You have made ' + Limits.getEmailInvocations() + ' email calls out of ' + Limits.getLimitEmailInvocations() + ' allowed');
```

Comment: you may be able to work around this by delegating to a WFR, Process Builder, or Flow where the limit is `1000 * # org users (max 2,000,000)`

Comment: Check this out: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25184/single-email-limit-exceeded-what-does-it-mean?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

There is a limit of 5,000 emails per day for emails sent to Lead and Contact records and emails listed in setToAddresses, setBbcAddresses, and setCcAddresses. The "no limit" on emails applies only to those sent using the User Interface.