# SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED Thats what I get from Triggers

Tags: trigger, email

I am having some problems sending emails using Salesforce to some of my contacts, I get this as result SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
I have looked thru and I have not seen anything reasonable to be called a resolution for this. I am sending emails using Triggers.

Said on line 22, so i had to check Line 22 and It came to this Line Messaging.sendEmail(mails);

I have contacts more than 10, How do i use Apex to send to them?
My code is Looking Like this :

```
trigger SendNotificationEmails on Contact (before insert) {
        List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > mails = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > ();
    for (Contact myContact : Trigger.new) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            //List < String > sendTo = new List < String > ();
            //sendTo.add(myContact.Email);
            //mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
            mail.setTargetObjectId( UserInfo.getUserId() );
            mail.setSaveAsActivity( false );
            mail.setReplyTo('fred_wisham@yopmail.com');
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Fred Wisham');
            List < String > ccTo = new List < String > ();
            ccTo.add('fred_wisham@yopmail.com');
            mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);
            mail.setSubject('Hi Friends How are you?');
            String body = 'Dear ' + myContact.FirstName + ', ';
            body += 'This is A test Email.';
            body += 'I am using this As a test Email to see how to send Messages with SalesForce';
            mail.setHtmlBody(body);
            mails.add(mail);
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
```

Comment: Are you using developer edition? if yes, then you can send only 10 emails per day.The limit is to use sendEmail method 10 times in a day not to send only 10 email/day. To send more then 10 email you need to create a logic which send email to more then one person by using single call of sendEmail  method by adding email it to setToAddresses[] method, setCcAddresses[] ,etc .

Comment: yes i am using developer edition

Comment: Solution provided in the reference  [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25184/single-email-limit-exceeded-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi Look at my source code, line 22 points to Messaging.sendEmail(mails) 
is there something I must do?

Comment: How do I sign up for non developer accounts? Any ideaS?

Comment: You need to purchase salesforce license.

Comment: In your case your using trigger to send an email to contact. If you insert contacts manually 10 contacts then trigger will call 10 times, that means  sendEmail method calls 10 times and limit is reached.

Comment: Emails to Contacts count against daily limits. Emails to Users do not. Can you use Community Users here (these are cheaper licenses and links Contacts to Users)? If you can, when sending the emails you simply need to translate the Contact IDs to their related User IDs before sending the email using the User IDs as the target IDs.

Comment: BTW you probably should use an email template with mailmerge to allow the email content to be more sophisticated and to allow the message to be managed separately to the code.

Comment: Additionally, avoid direct use of email addresses; use User IDs to avoid using daily limits.

Comment: Another issue, you are sending all the emails to the current user, not to the contacts, so the error will be due to use of an explicit email address for CC, not a User ID.

Comment: Final comment: best practice is to move logic into a trigger handler, not to code it directly in the trigger, and to have a single trigger per object type (so not triggers thay are specific to function like you have here).

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine. You are getting SingleEmailMessage Limit exception as you must be using Developer Edition of Salesforce Org. The Dev edition is logically separate environment, ideal as your initial development environment. You can sign up for as many Developer Edition org as you need. This allows you to build an application designed for any of the Salesforce production environments. For more information please refer to the following link:

[Get Started with Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.overview_edition.htm&type=5)

Please refer to the following link for SingleEmailMessage limit for Developer org:
[SingleEmailMessageLimit](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000337923&type=1)

[General Salesforce Email Limit](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000312442&type=1)

If you have a salesforce license then you can request to temporarily increase the daily limit as well.

Please refer to the following help article for the same:

[Increase the Daily Single Email Message limit for your organization](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000334435&type=1)

If you are interested in buying a salesforce product please refer to the following:

[Salesforce Product Pricing](https://www.salesforce.com/in/editions-pricing/overview/)

Comment: The code does not look fine - the target object ID is always the contextual user, not the contact, and the CC is an email address not a user ID, so immediately consumes part of the daily external email allowance. Even on a production org the limit is 5000 a day.