# Batch class finish method email exceeded

Tags: batch, singleemailmessage

I am trying to send the email with csv file attachment but it returns email limit is exceeded error, so I tried to send email using trigger there it work properly than why it is not working with batch class this is my code for sending single mail from finish method.

```java
public class BatchUserChange implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    public BatchUserChange(){
        System.debug('CONDTRUCTOR');
    }
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

        
        Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        System.debug('userId in start method '+userId);
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId FROM Account WHERE OwnerId=:userId]);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> acc) {
        System.debug('this is EXECUTE method ');
        System.debug('size ---- '+acc.size());
        User newOwner = [SELECT id, name FROM User WHERE name='kaumik gajjar'];
        System.debug('new user owner id :'+newOwner.id);
        for(Account a : acc){
            a.ownerId = newOwner.id;
        }
        System.debug('new list of acc to be update : '+acc);
        update acc;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        
 
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();            
                List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
                sendTo.add('nishitsuthar123@gmail.com');
                mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('test Email RR');
                mail.setSubject('test Email RR');
                String plaintxt = 'Hi oppopp';
                mail.setHtmlBody(plaintxt);
                mails.add(mail);
                Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using dev org because limit is very less ? Did you try sending email right after batch failed ? Did you check if email message limit is left ?

Comment: strange but yes I have tested trigger after running the batch class and email successfully sent but after one day my batch class work properly and yeah I am using dev edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce applies limits on the number of "external emails" that can be sent via Apex in a given 24 hour period. The limit depends on the type of org, but even with a production org this is just 5000.

I suggest you happened to roll into the next limit period when you tried to adopt trigger use, so hiding that the problem still exists.

The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000312442&type=1) is a little confusing, but what "external email" means in the Apex context is:

1. Any email address set using `setToAddresses`, `setCcAddresses` or `setBccAddresses` in a message.
2. A single email message sent to any target object via `setTargetObjectId` that is **not** a `User` record - this includes `Leads` and `Contacts`.

You should always try to use a `User` as the recipient and avoid explicitly setting an email address itself in Apex. Note that you can always try to reverse match an email address to a User record first, via something like:

```
List<String> emailAddresses = ...;
List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Email, Contact.Email FROM User WHERE User.Email IN :emailAddresses OR User.Contact.Email IN :emailAddresses];
```

You'll then have to deal with email addresses that couldn't be reverse matched to a User in this way by consuming your daily email limits.

It's worth also considering Daniel Ballinger's answer to this [previous Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/275705/50252).